# Wrong HTTP Status (0) when printing it from a Spring interceptor - When application is deployed as WAR in standalone TOMCAT

Tags: java, spring, rest, interceptor, spring-boot

I want to log the HTTP requests to a RESTful web service, by using an interceptor. I use spring-boot, version 1.1.5.RELEASE.

Here is my interceptor:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler;

public class WebRequestsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(WebRequestsInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        request.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        long startTime = (Long) request.getAttribute("startTime");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executeTime = endTime - startTime;
        logger.info(request.getMethod() + " " + request.getRequestURL() + "?"
                + request.getQueryString() + " Http Status "
                + response.getStatus() + " elapsed time : " + executeTime
                + "ms");

    }

}
```

The class that adds the interceptor:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new WebRequestsInterceptor());
    }

}
```

The problem that I am encountering is that the HTTP status that I am trying to log is always 0 when I deploy my application packaged as war in a standalone Tomcat (v. 7.0.50). When I run the application with embedded tomcat (provided by spring-boot), the HTTP Status is correct.

In debug mode, I can see an error occurred somehow, when I inspect the response : org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse@4456be6c and status is 0, indeed.

In the end I had to go for using an aspect to log the access to my web service, but the interceptor approach should work too.

Did anyone encounter the same problem? Thank you.

EDIT

A dummy rest controller, for which I want to intercept the requests:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello-world")
public class HelloWorldController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Greeting> sayHello(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Stranger")
            String name) {

        switch (name) {
        case "test":
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                    String.format(template, name)), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        case "name":
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                    String.format(template, name)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        case "spring":
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                    String.format(template, name)), HttpStatus.OK);
        default:
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                    String.format(template, name)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This information is also already present in an event emitted from the `DispatcherServlet`. You can create a `ApplicationListener` and listen  for `ServletRequestHandledEvent` events. Although that won't give you the status code (only success or failure). I would also suggest [registering an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) for this, as this looks like a bug/side effect to me.

Comment: Hi Maria, I am facing the same problem. I have registered this issue with spring https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12982 . Let me know if you find any alternative. I am using spring boot 1.1.10 and Jetty 8.1.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already fixed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/2fae4afe (i.e. will be in 1.1.6)

Comment: Hi Dave. I have upgraded my application so that it uses the new release of Spring Boot (1.1.6) and tested the WebRequestInterceptor. Now the status is whether 200 or 400, so success or failure, but that's not what I was expecting. When running the application with embedded Tomcat, I can see the correct states depending on my requests to the service, but when I deploy the app in a standalone Tomcat, I get 200 instead of 403. Why the behaviour is different between the two ways of executing the application? And how could I fix this status problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works for me (I get a 401 from a secure application for instance). Can you share your project and some steps to reproduce?

Comment: Does it work for you when you deploy the war in standalone Tomcat? Because that's the case when it doesn't work for me. All is well when running the application with embedded Tomcat.

Comment: I cannot share the project, and anyway the two classes, the interceptor and the class that registers it, have not changed.

Comment: Try with latest snapshots. If that doesn't work you need to work out how to share some code. I'm not interested in more than 2 or 3 classes anyway, so you can do it without revealing any secrets I'm sure.

Comment: Hi Dave. I really cannot share the project, so please take a look at the HelloWorldController that I have just added. And let me know if there are other classes that you would like to see in order to spot the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can do a hello world then put the whole project in GitHub (e.g. a pull request to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-issues). It's the only way to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: A wild guess: you may have added your own Security config and not explicitly ignored the /error path (see comments at the end if this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1548).